# Binary search tree remove node function not removing

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

My removal method consists of 4 if statements that tackle the 4 different kinds of removal in a binary search tree. Not sure where wrong but it didn't remove any node when I check it. Any help if appreciated. Thanks in advance'

I suspect the problems lies in are where I try to replace the node removal to be null

```
public class BinaryTree<T extends Comparable<T>> {

private class Node{

    private T data;
    private Node left;
    private Node right;


    // left and right child do not have to nessary exist
    public Node ( T data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
    }}

    private Node root;
    private int count = 0;

    public void add( T data) {
        if ( isEmpty()) {
            root = new Node(data);
            count++;
        }
        else {
            insert(data, root);
            count++;
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() { 
        return root == null;
    }

    public T getRoot()  {
        if ( root.data == null) {
            System.out.println("Root is empty");
            return null;
        }
        else {
        return  root.data;
    }}

    public Node getRootNode() {
        return root;
    }

    /*
     * Checking if the data is larger or lesser than the parent's data
     * If the data is smaller than the parent's data, node.left is created
     * If the data is bigger than the parent's data, node.right is created
     */
    private void insert( T data, Node node) {

        /*
         * If 1st obj is less than the 2nd obj return a neg
         * if 1st obj is more than the 2nd obj return a pos
         * if equal return 0
         */
        int compare = data.compareTo(node.data);
        if ( compare < 1 ){
            if (node.left == null ) {
                node.left = new Node(data);

            }

        // make node.left if it is filled  
            else {
                insert(data, node.left);
            }
        }

        else {
            if ( node.right == null) {
                node.right = new Node(data);
            }
            else {
                insert( data, node.right);
            }
        }
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return count;
    }

    public boolean search ( T data) {

        Node temp = searchInner(data, root);
        if ( temp.data == data) {
            System.out.println(temp.data);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }

    }


    public Node searchInner( T data, Node node) {

        int compare = data.compareTo(node.data);

        if ( getRoot() == data ) {
            return root;
        }

        if ( compare > 0) {
            return searchInner( data, node.right);  
        }

        if ( compare < 0 ) {
            return searchInner(data , node.left);
        }

        if ( compare == 0 ) {
            return node;
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Not found");
            return node;
        }

    }

    public void remove( T data) {
        remove1( root, data);
    }

    private Node remove1( Node node1, T data) {

        Node parent = root;
        Node node = root;
        Node temp;
        boolean isLeft = true;

        while ( node.data != data) {

            parent = node;

            if ( isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Unable to remove, root is empty");
                break;
            }

            if ( compare(data, node.data) < 0) {
                node = node.left;
                isLeft = true;
            }

            if ( compare(data, node.data) > 0) {
                node = node.right;
                isLeft = false;
            }

            else {
                // remove node if left child available
                if ( node.left == null && node.right != null) {

                    if ( isLeft) {
                        parent.left = node.right;
                    }

                    else {
                        parent.right = node.right;
                    }
                    count --;
                    break;
                }

                //remove node if right child available
                if ( node.right == null && node.left != null) {

                    if ( isLeft) {
                        parent.left = node.left;
                    }

                    else {
                        parent.right = node.left;
                    }
                    count --;
                    break;
                }

                // Remove node if 2 child available
                if ( node.left != null && node.right != null ) {

                    node = min(node.right);
                    node.right = remove1(node.right, node.data);

                }

                // remove node if no child available
                 if ( node.left == null && node.right == null) {
                    if (  isLeft ) {
                        parent.left = null;
                    }
                    else {
                        parent.right = null;
                    }
                    count --;
                    break;
                }

            }


        }
            return node;   
        }

    // fine the smallest node in the right subtree
    private Node min ( Node node1 ) {
        while ( node1.left != null) {
            node1 = node1.left;
        }
        return node1;
    }

    private int compare( T data, T data1) {
        return data.compareTo(data1);
    }

    public void printBST(T data) {
        printTree( root, data);
    }

    private void printTree( Node node, T data)
     {
        if(node == null) return;

        System.out.println(data + " + " + node.data);
        printTree(node.left , data);
        printTree(node.right , data);
     }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height(root);
    }

    private int height( Node node) {

        if  (node == null) return 0;
        else
            return 1 + Math.max(height(node.left), height(node.right));
        }

    public void print() {
        println(root);
    }

    private void println ( Node node) {

        LinkedList<T> q = new LinkedList<T>();
        q.add(node.data);

        if ( node == null) {
            return;
        }

        int size = getSize();
        while ( size > 0) {

                System.out.print(q);

            q.clear();
            if ( node.left != null) {
                q.add(node.left.data);
                size --;
            }
            if ( node.right != null) {
                q.add(node.right.data);
                size --;
            }
            if ( node.right != null&& node.left != null) {
                System.out.println();
            }
            if ( size > 1) {
                System.out.println(",");
            }
        }

    }

    public boolean sameTree( Node root1, Node root2) {

        if ( root1 == null && root2 == null) {
            return true;
        }

        if ( root1 != null && root2 != null) {
            return  root1.data == root2.data && sameTree(root1.left,root2.left) && sameTree(root1.right, root2.right);
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: When you compare ```if ( compare(data, node.data) < 0) ```, then you compare again ```if ( compare(data, node.data) > 0) ``` this second statement should be an else if

Comment: @Josep changed that but didn't really make the function work

Answer (score 0):

I have rewritten your BinaryTree class. I have added a new remove method, which uses your `min(Node node)` method and other one I have created, that only removes the minimum element of the tree. In addition, I have modified your Node class too by adding a new constructor and  added your size variable that was in BinaryTree class
I have modified all of this in order to make the method `remove()` working properly

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class BinaryTree<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    private class Node<T> { //Here we specify what the node contains

        private T data;
        private Node<T> left;
        private Node<T> right;
        private int size;

        public Node(T value) {
            this(value, null, null);
        }

        // left and right child do not have to nessary exist
        public Node(T data, Node<T> left, Node<T> right) {
            this.data = data;
            this.left = null;
            this.right = null;
            size = 1;
            if (left != null) {
                size += left.size;
            }
            if (right != null) {
                size += right.size;
            }
        }
    }
    private Node root;

    public BinaryTree() { //Added a constructor to set the root node to null
        root = null;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return root == null;
    }

    public T getRootData() { //Changed the name to other more clear
        if (root.data == null) {
            System.out.println("Root is empty");
            return null;
        } else {
            return (T) root.data;
        }
    }

    public Node getRootNode() {
        return root;
    }

    public void insert(T x) { //The new insert method
        root = insert(x, root);
    }

    protected Node<T> insert(T x, Node<T> actual) {
        //We check if the node exists, in case not we just create a new node
        if (actual == null) {
            return new Node<T>(x);
        }
        int cmp = compare(x, actual.data);
        if (cmp < 0) {
            actual.left = insert(x, actual.left);
        } else if (cmp > 0) {
            actual.right = insert(x, actual.right);
        } else {
            // If the node exists we just update his content
            actual.data = x;
        }
        actual.size = 1 + getSize(actual.left) + getSize(actual.right);
        return actual;
    }

     public int getSize() { //New method
        return getSize(root);
    }

    private int getSize(Node<T> actual) {
        if (actual == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return actual.size;
        }
    }

    public boolean search(T data) {

        Node temp = searchInner(data, root);
        if (temp.data == data) {
            System.out.println(temp.data);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }

    public Node searchInner(T data, Node node) {

        int compare = data.compareTo((T) node.data);

        if (getRootData() == data) {
            return root;
        }

        if (compare > 0) {
            return searchInner(data, node.right);
        }

        if (compare < 0) {
            return searchInner(data, node.left);
        }

        if (compare == 0) {
            return node;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not found");
            return node;
        }

    }

    public void remove(T data) {

        remove1(root, data);
    }

    private Node remove1(Node actual, T data) {
        if (actual == null) {
            return actual;
        }
        int cmp = compare(data, (T) actual.data);
        //Check whether the value is lesser greater or equal than the one we are just visiting
        if (cmp < 0) {
            actual.left = remove1(actual.left, data);
        } else if (cmp > 0) {
            actual.right = remove1(actual.right, data);
        } else {
            if (actual.right == null) {
                return actual.left;
            }
            if (actual.left == null) {
                return actual.right;
            }
            actual.data = min(actual.right).data;
            actual.right = removeMin(actual.right);
        }
        return actual;
    }

    public Node removeMin() {
        //A new method to remove the minimum element
        Node min = min(root);
        root = removeMin(root);
        return min;
    }

    private Node removeMin(Node actual) {
        if (actual.left == null) {
            return actual.right;
        }
        actual.left = removeMin(actual.left);
        actual.size--;
        return actual;
    }

    // fine the smallest node in the right subtree
    private Node min(Node node1) {
        while (node1.left != null) {
            node1 = node1.left;
        }
        return node1;
    }

    private int compare(T data, T data1) {
        return data.compareTo(data1);
    }

    public void printBST(T data) {
        printTree(root, data);
    }

    private void printTree(Node node, T data) {
        if (node == null) {
            return;
        }

        System.out.println(data + " + " + node.data);
        printTree(node.left, data);
        printTree(node.right, data);
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height(root);
    }

    private int height(Node node) {

        if (node == null) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1 + Math.max(height(node.left), height(node.right));
        }
    }

    public void print() {
        println(root);
    }

    private void println(Node node) {

        LinkedList<T> q = new LinkedList<T>();
        q.add((T) node.data);

        if (node == null) {
            return;
        }

        int size = getSize();
        while (size > 0) {

            System.out.print(q);

            q.clear();
            if (node.left != null) {
                q.add((T) node.left.data);
                size--;
            }
            if (node.right != null) {
                q.add((T) node.right.data);
                size--;
            }
            if (node.right != null && node.left != null) {
                System.out.println();
            }
            if (size > 1) {
                System.out.println(",");
            }
        }

    }

    public boolean sameTree(Node root1, Node root2) {

        if (root1 == null && root2 == null) {
            return true;
        }

        if (root1 != null && root2 != null) {
            return root1.data == root2.data && sameTree(root1.left, root2.left) && sameTree(root1.right, root2.right);
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

I hope this helps to you

Comment: Can you explain this part?
private Node removeMin(Node actual) {
        if (actual.left == null) {
            return actual.right;
        }
        actual.left = removeMin(actual.left);
        actual.size--;
        return actual;
    }

Not sure how it actually removes the min

Comment: We create a BinaryTree and insert numbers from 0 to 9, for example. Before doing anything we know that the minimum element is the first one, the node that contains the 0 value. The tree before doing anything seems: 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> ... -> 9 All this nodes except the 9, has a node on his right. When we call ```removeMin()``` we are removing the minimum node on this line ```root = removeMin(root)```. In the lines you have posted we are finding the second minimun node, just to put it on the root of the tree

Comment: You're saying this line {return actual.right;} returns the second minimum node?

Comment: Yes, if we consider that elements that are lesser than the root are on the left side of the tree, and elements greater than the root are on the right side. Try by yourself, creating a small tree and follow the method, you will find the second minimum element